# Как получить индекс элемента с определенным классом на jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько кнопок с классами `.js-practice_button`:

```
<ul class="practices_list js-practices_buttons">
    <li class="practice_item"><span class="practice_button js-practice_button" data-target="js-practice1">Недвижимость</span></li>
    <li class="practice_item"><span class="practice_button js-practice_button" data-target="js-practice2">Иммиграция</span></li>
    <li class="practice_item"><span class="practice_button current js-practice_button" data-target="js-practice3">Банковское дело</span></li>
    <li class="practice_item"><span class="practice_button js-practice_button" data-target="js-practice4">Судебный процесс</span></li>
</ul>
```

Нужно получить индекс кнопки с классом `current`. Как это правильно сделать?

Пытаюсь так:

```
let currentIndex = $(".js-practice_button.current").index();
```

Но значение всегда 0, у какой бы кнопки класс `current` не присутствовал.

Comment: Наверное потому что этот элемент всегда один. `$('.js-practice_button').index($('.current'));`

Comment: Зачес вам индекс элемента, если можно обратится к самому элементу? Если нужен индекс прям, то отбирайте все кнопки и в них в цикле ищите нужный класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то такое хотели?

По идее если просить индекс то подразумевается что у вас есть список
и элемент который вы ищите.
так вот список это

```
$(".js-practice_button")
```

а то что вы ищите  это

```
$(".js-practice_button.current")
```

```js
let currentIndex = $(".js-practice_button").index($(".js-practice_button.current"));

console.log(currentIndex);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="practices_list js-practices_buttons">
    <li class="practice_item"><span class="practice_button js-practice_button" data-target="js-practice1">Недвижимость</span></li>
    <li class="practice_item"><span class="practice_button js-practice_button" data-target="js-practice2">Иммиграция</span></li>
    <li class="practice_item"><span class="practice_button current js-practice_button" data-target="js-practice3">Банковское дело</span></li>
    <li class="practice_item"><span class="practice_button js-practice_button" data-target="js-practice4">Судебный процесс</span></li>
</ul>
```